# How to Handle Model Binding After Using DisplayFormat Attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, usability

I am working on financial software which uses a lot of currency values and percentages.  Without putting any thought into usability, if you create a default TextBox and bind it to a decimal `0.00M`, it appears to the user as `0.00`.  It is ambiguous whether they should enter 6% as 6.00 or 0.06.  You also run into the problem where .065 displays as 0.06, which makes the value appear incorrect to the user.

To clarify the intent of the numbers, I am using display attributes like this:

```
[Display(Name = "State Tax Rate")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
public decimal StateRate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Combined Tax Rate")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
public decimal CombinedRate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "County Tax Rate")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
public decimal CountyRate { get; set; }
```

Now 6.5% is displayed as 6.50%, which is better from a usability standpoint, but when you post the form to an ASP.Net Core MVC controller, the values do not bind.  Simply stripping the percentage sign causes it to bind at 650%.  The approach I am taking is to use JQuery to clean up the data before the post takes place:

```
// deal with percentages:
// 6.5% does not bind, but is displayed to the user.
// 6.5 binds incorrectly (650%)
// .065 is desired format
$(function () {
    $('#my-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();                     // avoid default post routine

        // change "6.50%" to 6.5
        var stateRate = parseFloat($('#StateRate').val().replace('%', ''));             
        var combinedRate = parseFloat($('#EstCombinedRate').val().replace('%', ''));
        var countyRate = parseFloat($('#EstCountyRate').val().replace('%', ''));

        // change 6.5 to .065 - leave 0.065 alone.
        if (stateRate > 1) {
            stateRate = stateRate / 100.0;  
        }
        if (combinedRate > 1) {
            combinedRate = combinedRate / 100.0;
        }
        if (countyRate > 1) {
            countyRate = countyRate / 100.0;
        }

        // put the cleaned up values back into the form fields
        $('#StateRate').val(stateRate);     
        $('#CombinedRate').val(combinedRate);
        $('#CountyRate').val(countyRate);

        // make ajax request
        $.post(
            '/MyController/EditTaxRates'
            $(this).serialize(),
            function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $.notify('Data saved successfully!', { position: "top center" });
            }
        ).fail(function () {
            $.notify('Error saving data.', { position: "top center" });
        });
    });
});
```

This is working properly for the most part, but I need to implement this a lot of places, and this adds a lot of code to solve a seemingly fundamental and simple issue.  Also, it fails for a county tax rate such as 0.5%, which binds as 50% when using this code as written.  Are there are any built-in tricks such as attributes or Razor magic that will cause the data to bind properly without using javascript, or is there a best practice that addresses this problem?

Comment: You might want to look at [mvc-numericinput](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-numericinput) as an option

Comment: In addition, a `[Range]` attribute can be use to limit values between 0 and 1 for percentages.